# Getting error like "are you missing a using directive or an assembly refrence?" in subsonic

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, subsonic, subsonic3

I am developing MVC 3 application and its first time i am using subsonic.

I get this error (The type or namespace name 'name of my tables' could not be found()are you missing a using directive or an assembly refrence?)) in Context.cs file when i compile my ASP.NET MVC3 Web Application. I follow these guide http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Setting_up_SubSonic_3.0 but i cant solve this problem.Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using ActiveRecord T4 templates right?

In ActiveRecord.cs there should be a class for each of your tables. Have they been created correctly?

Also, in Settings.ttinclude there should be a namespace setting. Is that namespace surrounding the code in your Context.cs and ActiveRecord.cs?